# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult' - Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, I'm trying to return a view but I'm getting the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'" on **`return View();`**

My controller looks as follow

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc;
//other using..

[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Cal(EmailFormModel emailFormModel)
        {... //controller code
return View(); <--- error happens here
}
```

for this specific controller, I have to use `IActionResult`

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Does your class inherit from the controller class?

Like: `public class HomeController : Controller`

Comment: yes, my class inherit from the controller class - public class HomeController : Controller